# How do I access a variable inside an eventlistener class?

Tags: java, scope

My code goes something like this:

```
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        class openFileListener implements ActionListener {

            public String[] hex;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


            try {
                // Read byte data of .bmp file
                byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(pathname);

            } catch(IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    } //end of class

    openFileListener listener = new openFileListener();
    openButton.addActionListener(listener);



    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to access the contents in "byte[] data" so I can manipulate it.
Right now, I've been doing everything inside the event listener, but I don't think that is very clean.

I'd like to be able to call something like System.out.println(data[0]) in my main.

Comment: Use model, which can connected between different aspects of your code. Understand though, because of the way your code is setup, `data` will be irrelevant until after the `ActionListener` is called. Most GUIs are event driven, meaning things don't happen in a sequential order

Answer (score 1):

`byte[] data` should be an instance variable, just like `String[] hex`. Also, don't define your classes inside functions. Make hex and data private instance variables of your class and provide getters for them. Also, readAllBytes() takes a variable of type `java.nio.file.Path` and you are probably passing in a String.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Application {

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 200;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 200;
    private static String pathName = "...";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JButton openButton = new JButton();
            frame.getContentPane().add(openButton);
            OpenFileListener openFileListener = new OpenFileListener();
            openButton.addActionListener(openFileListener);

            frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    static class OpenFileListener implements ActionListener {

        private String[] hex;
        private byte[] data;

        public String[] getHex() {
            return hex;
        }

        public byte[] getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pathName));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```